# Tag [android-listview] using [listview]

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions, tag-synonym-process, user-interface

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659124/listview-addheaderview-doesnt-set-parent) and set the tag [android-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-listview), but the tag [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) appeared instead. On the other hand, I also set the tag [android-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-view), and this one appeared correctly.

Is this a bug? Or is the tag simply redirected because that's the one that should be used? If that's the case, it's not clear which tags should have the `android` prefix and which shouldn't.

Comment: That tag is being redirected via synonym. If you go to [the info page for a tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/listview/info), you can see in the sidebar what synonyms are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [android-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-listview) tag is a synonym of the [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) tag, so it got replaced automatically.

See [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> The system organizes tags in a master–synonym relationship. All uses of the synonym tag for any given master tag are automatically converted to the master tag. So, users can enter a synonym tag when writing a question, but the master tag will be displayed when the question is loaded.

Comment: It is no longer a synonym BTW