# This tag needs to be made more [unobtrusive]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag [unobtrusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unobtrusive) has 73 questions and no tag wiki.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. It's an adjective.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes. Every program is trying to be as obtrusive as possible, so avoiding being unobtrusive is on-topic.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

If it's talking about unobtrusive javascript, then [unobtrusive-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unobtrusive-javascript) should be used instead.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm not sure is a valid answer to one of the questions...

Comment: Note that we do have [tag:unobtrusive-validation], with a proper excerpt, and a significant portion of the questions should probably be retagged to that.

Comment: "Every program is trying to be as obtrusive as possible" -- not strictly true. Certain classes of software intend to be obtrusive (example: A warning message on an avionics display, or even a mobile phone ringtone). But point taken nonetheless :)

Comment: I also personally think that questions about obtrusive vs unobtrusive UI, or how to make an unobtrusive UI, are off-topic here, and should likely be posted on [ux.se], keeping in mind the expectations of a question there. Yes, UX is part of every program. But many aspects of it are certainly off-topic here.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Also unobtrusive JavaScript, which also has its own tag. Incidentally, that makes at least two distinct topics (both of which are evidently fairly common usages of the term), so clearly this tag does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts.

Comment: Yeah, the puns are back.

Comment: This should probably be a retag, cleanup or synonym request, since the tag should *not* just be removed in most cases.

Comment: @Dukeling synonimization is *not* the solution. The tag has *multiple* meanings! By synonymizing you are collapsing its multiples meaning into one, which certainly will be wrong.

Comment: @Braiam Synonimization should include going through the applicable questions and removing the tag where the usage doesn't correspond to the intended usage. But I did mention 2 other options as well, either or both of which may or may not be more appropriate, depending on how this tag is actually used.

Comment: @Dukeling no, because *future* uses of the tag would be automagically modified. People aren't aware enough to figure it out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338056/792066

Comment: @Braiam Not every tags needs to be unambiguous based on name alone, the cost of having the tag (fixing questions with incorrect tagging) just needs to be lower than the benefit of having the tag (which includes the cost of what would've been correct usages of the tag not happening and repeated burnination). But I did mention 2 other options as well - I wasn't saying "this should be a synonym request" as much as I was saying "this shouldn't be a burninate request".

Comment: @Dukeling "Not every tags needs to be unambiguous" [citation-needed!] "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into **specific, well-defined categories**." Anything ambiguous would, by definition, not be specific, nor well-defined.

Comment: @Braiam You seem to have missed the "based on name alone" part.

Comment: @Dukeling but the name is what a tag *is*! The name defines the category of the questions it should be applied.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A lot of these questions are about unobtrusive validation, which is an actual topic that already has its own tag. We can just retag the ones that are worth keeping.

A lot more of these questions are about Unobtrusive JavaScript, which again is [a real topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) that already has its own tag. Again, retag the questions that are about this that are worth keeping and close the rest.

(By "real topic," I mean "something that you can have actual knowledge about" - you can't really be an expert in "unobtrusive" because it's not a real topic).

Incidentally, this answers the last question that you weren't sure about: given that I just gave two common meanings of the term, it clearly does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts.

It also strongly suggests that this tag is redundant: a lot of these questions apparently should've been using one of the two tags I mentioned instead.